# In macOS, how often is /tmp deleted?

Tags: macos

How often is /tmp deleted? I thought it was cleaned out boot time and every three days if you don't reboot, but I can't find any authoritative source for this.

I'm running the latest 10.6. (I suppose I would be interested in changes in this behavior in previous OS versions.)

Comment: How about the per-user temporary folders in `/var/folders/` ?

Answer (score 172, accepted):

Short answer: by default, files that aren't accessed in three days are deleted from /tmp

Long answer:

This was changed significantly in MacOS Sonoma 14

Prior to Sonoma, it works like this:

1. `launchd` sets up `/usr/sbin/periodic daily` to run every 86400 seconds (1 day) (definition in `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.periodic-daily.plist`). Older versions of Mac OS scheduled it to run at 3:15 am each day.
2. `/usr/sbin/periodic daily` runs the scripts in `/etc/periodic/daily`, including `110.clean-tmps`.
3. `110.clean-tmps` uses `find` to delete files not accessed (using the `-atime` and `-mtime` parameters to `find`) in `$daily_clean_tmps_days` days which aren't listed in `$daily_clean_tmps_ignore`.
4. Those two variables (and other related variables) are defined in `/etc/periodic.conf`. (Since OS 10.7 there is a file `/etc/defaults/periodic.conf` which defines the *defaults*, but for overwriting these defaults you should still create `/etc/periodic.conf` – see the periodic.conf(5) manual page.) If you haven't modified this file, `$daily_clean_tmps_days` is set to 3.

`periodic daily` logs its output to `/var/log/daily.out`. Files deleted from `/tmp` are logged under the heading "Removing old temporary files:".

In MacOS Sonoma, this was migrated to be controlled more directly with `launchd`

1. There is a new launch daemon configured specifically for cleaning `/tmp` in `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.tmp_cleaner.plist`
2. Using `StartCalendarInterval`, it runs `/usr/libexec/tmp_cleaner` daily at hour 0 (i.e. midnight)
3. `tmp_cleaner` is a shell script that is very similar to `110.clean-tmps` used pre-Sonoma *but* it does not provide any easy way to override the 3 day setting. You'd have to manually edit this file (and do it again on OS update0

Comment: Note in 10.7 periodic.conf has moved to /etc/defaults .

Comment: Does the same apply to $TMPDIR?

Comment: No, I don't believe that it does. There's no reference to `$TMPDIR` in any of the config files mentioned.

Comment: I have some indications that files are also cleared from /tmp on restart of the machine (I had a few gig of Blender renderings in /tmp that went poof and I think that they left this world when I restarted the machine)

Comment: _n.b._ This answer is 7.5 years old at this point, macOS is now at 10.13 and I'm using 10.11. While the short answer is still correct (3 days), some of the details have definitely changed. For example, in 10.11, I don't see the line that schedules this for 3:15 a.m. in `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.periodic-daily.plist`.

I've not had the time to learn more about the boot process to determine how `/tmp` is cleared at boot time (per the comment by @Reb.Cabin above)

Comment: Using OSX 10.14.5, can confirm that /tmp seems to be wiped out on reboot.

Comment: Instructions appear to be current as of Aug-2019 / MacOS Mojave 10.14.6.

Comment: I dug into find more details on when this is run (I'm currently on 10.14.6 but the latest version of MacOS is 10.15.6). As I noted on Feb 16, 2018, periodic daily is no longer scheduled to run at 3:15 a.m. It's now defined to run at an interval of 86400 seconds (1 day). I've analyzed the data in `/var/log/daily.out` and see that it has run at any hour of the day. Since the beginning of 2020, the average time between runs has been ~26.5 hours, minimum 6 hrs and max at 10+ days (when I've been on vacation).

Comment: Good as of August-2021 / macOS Big Sur

Comment: I'm assuming that if you have a long-running program that actively has a file open, then that file won't get deleted by the periodic sweep? PS from a single test, /tmp is deleted on boot on macOS 12.4 Monterey

Comment: I’d guess that would update the access time, so the process that cleans out /tmp would not delete it.

Comment: Still valid for macOS Monterey 12.4

Comment: Updated the answer with significant changes in MacOS Sonoma 14