# When are the temp files/directories in “/var/folders” automatically deleted in macOS?

Tags: macos, temporary-files

1. How often and under what conditions are files under `/var/folders/` removed?
2. Where can I find ***any*** official documentation or notes on this? I've searched but haven't even found a mention of it.
3. If an application creates a file under `/var/folders/`, is it possible for that file to be removed by the system before the application quits?'
4. Bonus question: Why isn't this information easier/possible to find? Is this a gap in Apple's documentation, or an intentional omission?

---

Here's a related question, but it's 10 years old and refers to `/tmp` and not `var/folders`: [In macOS, how often is /tmp deleted?](https://superuser.com/questions/187071/in-macos-how-often-is-tmp-deleted)

Here's almost the same question from 51 weeks ago with 0 answers: [In OSX when are /var/folders deleted](https://superuser.com/questions/1494569/in-osx-when-are-var-folders-deleted)

Comment: Interesting question. Did you see this [very well written — and detailed — post](http://www.magnusviri.com/what-is-var-folders.html) on the internals of that directory structure here? No real clarity on when those contents get automatically deleted, but could help.